# Exact match on value in object/array

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a problem with counting the number of occurences of a string from an array in a field in an object.

The XML below has 3 'Level3' items with 1 'TextLine' field each.

I need to count how many times each text in the variable 'texts' occurs in the payload.

```
fun getVasCount(texts) = 
    sizeOf (Level1.*Level2.*Level3.*TextLine filter (texts contains $))
```

So instead of getting the count:2 I got the count:3 because 'a text' is a substring of 'This is a text'

```
var texts = {
    "This is a text": "",
    "This is another text": ""
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Level1
    xmlns:ns="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd">
    <Level2>
        <Level3>
            <TextLine>This is a text</TextLine>
        </Level3>
        <Level3>
            <TextLine>This is a text</TextLine>
        </Level3>
        <Level3>
            <TextLine>a text</TextLine>
        </Level3>
    </Level2>
</ns:Level1>
```

Comment: Why instead of contains you don't use `==` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it is to count occurrences for each different texts grouping them by value and counting how many elements are in each group.
And then modify your `texts` object with the counts.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var texts = {
    "This is a text": "",
    "This is another text": ""
}
var textLines = payload.Level1.*Level2.*Level3.*TextLine default []
var grouped = textLines 
    groupBy $ 
    mapObject (groupValues, text) -> {(text): sizeOf(groupValues)}
---
texts mapObject {($$): grouped[$$] default 0}
```

The result would be:

```
{
  "This is a text": 2,
  "This is another text": 0
}
```

Note: Not really modifying `texts`, since objects are immutable, it's creating a new one.